# How to enable IIS7 failed request tracing for the Sitecore media library?

Tags: iis-7, sitecore, sitecore6

I'd like to enable failed request tracing for a group of media items in the Sitecore media library. I initially tried to do this by using a custom setting for the rule so I could use the path:

```
~/media/mystuff/*
```

Unfortunately, request tracing doesn't allow a tilda ~ in the path and only allows a single wildcard *. The path also has to be relative to the directory. The tilda is a necessary part of the path, and I want to trace everything in the mystuff folder.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the media prefix sitecore applies to media library urls. It's stored in `web.config` in the setting `Media.MediaLinkPrefix` - we've changed ours to a dash:

```
<setting name="Media.MediaLinkPrefix" value="-/media" />
```

There's a note in the `web.config` comments about adding a corresponding entry in the `<customHandlers>` section:

```
<handler trigger="-/media/" handler="sitecore_media.ashx" />
```

To complete the picture, add a url rewrite to map `~` to `-`, so any indexed media still works.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the answer - do you know if there is any way to do this without changing the prefix and rewriting URLs? We might go that route if we can't find another solution, but I was hoping for an "On" button :-)